# Reminders.app two-way synchronisation logic

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, eventkit, ekeventkit

I want my app to synchronise with the Reminders.app. (my app utilizes Core Data)

I've already done a prototype and it works, but there are some bugs I can't think through.

Right now my sync algorithm looks like this:

1.Listen to `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` notification and when called sync

2.First I'm iterating over my local Calendars, and if they don't exist in Reminders.app I'm adding them.

This is a pretty bad design because if I delete a calendar in Reminders.app and if it's added to my app, it gets added again to Reminders.app. It's going to be much better to know if a calendar has been deleted.

3.Then I iterate over each Calendar from Reminders.app, and if this calendar doesn't exist in my local records I add them to my local.app. If it does exist, then I'm updating its title.

4.I'm fetching all the reminders from my `EKEventStore`

5.I'm iterating through all my local reminders, and if they don't exist in Reminders.app I'm adding them.

Again the problem with deleting - same story as calendar deleting.

6.I'm iterating through all Reminders.app reminders and if they don't exist in my app I'm adding them in my local.app. If they do exist I'm updating all values.

It's all fine, until I hit this problem with deleting. I see that `EKObject` has some methods that can help me, but I can't figure them out. How do I do this properly and is there something that I can do for optimisation?

Answer (score 0):

What about keeping track of what reminders you have scheduled in a .plist?
So if your algorithm is checking for what's missing against the .plist, and if it shows as having already been added in the .plist but isn't in the calendar, that means it was deleted.

```
　 //Create dictionary that keeps track of your reminders

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self remindersDictionary];

[dictionary setValue:local.fireDate forKey:title];
[dictionary setValue:@"TRUE" forKey:addedToReminders];

[plistDictionary setValue:dictionary forKey:@"reminders"];
[plistDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

+(NSMutableDictionary *)remindersDictionary
{
NSString *searchPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

plistPath = [searchPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];
plistDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [plistDictionary valueForKey:@"reminders"];

return dictionary;

}
```

Comment: No, I'm already using Core data, I don't need another storage.

Comment: What about adding a property to your reminder data model what tracks if it has been added or not?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `date changed`-property or something similar? This would make things easier.

Ideally you save the information that a cal is deleted somewhere. Then - on sync - you can check if the calendar (you're about to add) was deleted recently or not. If thats the case you can delete the local calendar and delete the info for deletion too. So the list stays clean unless you delete an item and it is successfully synced to the counterpart.

Or if you want to do it by date, you can compare `lastSyncedDate` and `calendarModifiedDate` (just two examples). But this isn't such a nice solution. You have to consider timezones, time changes and user interaction with time eg. settings changed.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly my Q - how do I save the information that a calendar is deleted? I'm talking when it's deleted from the Reminders.app, when a calendar is deleted from my app, I delete it from my persistent store and from Reminders.app, and it's ok.

Comment: you can also have a third calendar which represents the last known state of the `Reminders.app`. Then you have one-way from Reminders App to your temporary cal. Means if the `Reminders.app` is missing a calendar you will delete it in your temporary cal and voila, you have a deletion info for that calendar. And you have one-way from your local cal to the temporary cal. Merging the differences and taking note of the deletion info

Comment: I've been thinking about this and it seems like an overkill, but its a smart suggestion. I'm still open for advices though.